# Combining all Block Group shapefiles together as one

Tags: shapefile, r, census

I'm trying to load in all the shapefiles from the Census found here (https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/BG/), and merge them all together as one large shapefile for the entire US overcoming issues with duplicate polygons.

I adopted code found from a question asked previously but could not get it to work as it stops once I hit state 6.

> ```
> Error in download.file(x, destfile = path, mode = "wb") : cannot open URL'ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/BG/tl_2019_06_bg.zip'
>
> In addition: warning messages: 1: In download.file(x, destfile = path, mode = "wb") : downloaded length 29680232 != reported length 50020624
> ```

```
library(RCurl) 
library(rgdal)

# get the directory listing
u <- 'ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/BG/'
f <- paste0(u, strsplit(getURL(u, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, ftplistonly = TRUE), 
                        '\\s+')[[1]])

# download and extract to tempdir/shps
invisible(sapply(f, function(x) {
  path <- file.path(tempdir(), basename(x))
  download.file(x, destfile=path, mode = 'wb')
  unzip(path, exdir=file.path(tempdir(), 'shps'))
}))

# read in all shps, and prepend shapefile name to IDs
shps <- lapply(sub('\\.zip', '', basename(f)), function(x) {
  shp <- readOGR(file.path(tempdir(), 'shps'), x)
  shp <- spChFIDs(shp, paste0(x, '_', sapply(slot(shp, "polygons"), slot, "ID")))
  shp
})

# rbind to a single object
shp <- do.call(rbind, as.list(shps))


# write out to wd/USA.shp
writeOGR(shp, '.', 'USA', 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

Comment: Shapefile has a 2GiB file length limitation. You are likely blowing past that pretty quickly. Use a file format created this millennium instead.

Comment: Incorrect; individually these SHP files do not exceed the 2GB limit. Even together, they don't. It is still less than the 2GB limit on shapefiles. I'm looking for guidance on how or where the mistake lies above.

Comment: Use Ogr2ogr and a bash loop there are plenty of answers to that on this site

Comment: Looks like a problem downloading the data for state 6 rather than in combining them. What happens if you start the file list at state 6 (by removing the first five elements)? Does it fail on state 6 again? Or later on?

Comment: I found out the census has a full shapefile available for the block group that I needed so I just pulled it.